# 法人でアプリを配布したい場合、Apple Developer ProgramにOrganizationとして登録すべきか。

Tags: apple

会社としてapple developer programに登録する場合、D-U-N-S numberとか面倒なものが多いと思いますが、小さい会社などだと個人開発者が開発者の名前を会社名にしたりして、配布する場合も少なくないのですかね？

Answer (score 5):

これはオフトピックな話題だと思いますが…。

「法人格としてアプリを配布したい場合」と解釈すると、組織として登録すべきです。

そもそもAppleがDUNSNumberを要求するのは、架空の企業による登録を防ぐためです。個人開発者名を会社名にして登録することが可能だと思えませんが、これは明確に「すべきではない」と言えると思います。

個人事業主などで法人であることの証明手続きを回避するために、個人名で登録されるケース自体はあります。この場合、AppStoreの販売者名は個人名になるほか、チームの管理が行えません。

なお個人としてDeveloper Programに登録しても、後から法人化した場合などに組織としての登録に移行することが可能です。

---

- [メンバーシップの選択](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/jp/)
- [プログラムへの登録](https://developer.apple.com/jp/support/ios/enrollment.php)

まずは公式のドキュメントを参照し、必要に応じてサポートに問い合わせると良いと思います。